# Jasmine Test Cases for click and toggle events

Tags: jasmine, jasmine-jquery

```
Struggling on writing the testcases on click,toggle,slideUp,fade events.

How do I write jasmine test cases to check if div is clicked or not and the slideUp and down and toggle events. Is there a provision in jasmine to test them.
```

Have listed my code having click test case for reference.

```
SpecRunner.html file 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.3.4</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib_jasmine/jasmine-   2.3.4/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib_jasmine/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.css">
  <script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="lib_jasmine/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script src="lib_jasmine/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script src="lib_jasmine/jasmine-2.3.4/boot.js"></script>
  <script src="lib_jasmine/jasmine-2.3.4/jasmine-jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- include source files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/eigMain.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/sinon.js"></script>
  <!-- include spec files here... -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/specEig.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>

 js file for reference

    $('#screenPane').click(function(e){
            $('#Panel,.FixedHeader').toggleClass('fullscreen'); 
            $('#eIcon').toggle();
            $('#cIcon').toggle();
            $(".Col").toggle();
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('#total-results').offset().top}, 800);
            $('#nav_up').fadeIn('slow'); 
            $('#nav_down').hide(); 
                });
```

Spec.js file having click event test case on it. It gives me ERROR : Expected event [object Object] to have been triggered on [object Object]. Also, toggle test case fails to execute.

```
it ("should invoke the screenPane click event.", function() {
    spyOnEvent($('#screenPane'), 'click');
    $('#screenPane').click();
    expect('click').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn($('#screenPane'));
  });
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

While most tags accept or react to a click event, detecting it may prove difficult on the various platforms and browsers. You would probably be better checking to see if the CSS classes that `toggle()` deals with have been swapped in response to the click. For checking anything that is going to get moved around, simply check the starting X/Y coordinates and then compare them to the ones when the animation is finished and just check to see if they are different (so as to not create a brittle situation with strictly defined values.)

```
//Checking coordinates
it ("should invoke the screenPane click event.", function() {
    var coords = $('screenPane').offset();
    $('#screenPane').click();
    var newCoords = $('screenPane').offset();
    expect(newCoords).not.toEqual(coords);
  });

//Checking classes
it ("should invoke the screenPane click event.", function() {
    var classes = $('screenPane').val('class');
    $('#screenPane').click();
    var newClasses = $('screenPane').val('class');
    expect(classes).not.toEqual(newClasses);
  });
```

Comment: Getting TypeError: expect(...).not.equal is not a function on invoking above functions. Am I missing some js file??

Comment: Very sorry, slipped back into chai for a minute while writing that. It should have been `toEqual` instead of `equal`. Also, you might have to check either the X or Y coordinate instead of the whole object as I don't remember how Jasmine will act when two objects are compared and their values are not the same. It should work, but just in case you have problems, you should be able to get around that with a custom matcher (http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/custom_matcher.html)